# Mocking a class with delegates using Moq

Tags: c#, delegates, moq

The code I have write looks like this:

```
public class DelegatesClass
{
    IntPtr lib = IntPtr.Zero;

    public delegate Boolean _SetMode(Int32 nMode);
    public _SetMode SetMode;

    public DelegatesClass()
    {
        IntPtr funcPtr;

        lib = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(fullDllName);

        funcPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(lib, "SetMode");
        SetMode = (_SetMode)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcPtr, typeof(_SetMode;));
    }
}

public class DelegatesUser
{
    public DelegatesUser()
    {
        //...
    }

    public SetUserMode(int mode)
    {
        DelegatesClass ds = new DelegatesClass();
        ds.SetMode(mode);

        //...
    }

}
```

I have to use a win32 dll in my project, so I created 'DelegateClass'. This does nothing else then making the dll functions available using delegates.
My real code is written in a separate class 'DelegateUser'. This way I should be able to mock DelegateClass, and make my code testable.

My test code looks like this:

```
        var dc= new Mock<DelegatesClass>();

        dc.Setup(x => x.SetMode(It.IsAny<Int32>())
            .Returns(true);

        DelegatesUser du = new DelegatesUser();
        du.SetUserMode(1);
```

When running the test I get a 'System.ArgumentException' saying: 'Expression is not a method invocation'.

I suppose the problem is that I am trying to fake a delegate, not a real function. How can I make my test code work?

Comment: Can you go more traditional route of using interfaces? Side note: your `DelegatesUser` explicitly news up the `DelegateClass` so your test will do nothing useful even when you succeed to mock the `DelegateClass`.

Comment: Why not just use `Func<int, bool>` instead of introducing the (strange looking) nested type `DelegatesClass._SetMode`?

Comment: Using the `Func<int,bool>` is indeed a more elegant solution. But it does not seem to solve the problem that it cannot be faked (unless I am doing something completely wrong ...)

Answer (score 2):

You can't mock field.

Since `SetDelegate` is just public field you can assign it directly:

```
var dc = new DelegatesClass();
dc.SetMode = nMode => true;
```

Notes:

- consider using interfaces as it would be easier to read/understand as more traditional approach
- you need to inject dependency on   `DelegatesClass` into `DelegatesUser` as explicit `new DelegatesClass()` will not allow you to pass mocked instance.

Sample for injection:

```
public class DelegatesUser
{
    DelegatesClass ds;
    public DelegatesUser(DelegatesClass ds)
    {
        this.ds = ds;
        //...
    }

    public SetUserMode(int mode)
    {
        // use "ds" passed in constructor instead of new DelegatesClass();
        ds.SetMode(mode);

        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei!
Concerning your remark about injecting the dependency: You are right, and I did this is my real code. The code in my question was just to illustrate my problem :-)
I will immediately try your suggestion to set the field directly.

Comment: Your arrow `() => true` should look more like `i => true`, given the signature of this delegate type.